# Drag and drop allDay events in fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a full calendar holding both allDay and normal events. I am using versio 6.1.8 of fullCalendar.

I am having problems dragging and dropping allDay events from one allday slot to another. I can however drop then to any other slot in any day. The event is simply bouncing back to the event that previously was.

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
<html>

  <head>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/6.1.8/index.global.min.js'></script>

    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          events: [{
              title: 'event1',
              start: '2023-12-12'
            },

          ],
          height: 800,
          initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
          eventColor: '#292b2c',
          headerToolbar: false,
          themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
          duration: {
            days: 7
          },
          showNonCurrentDates: false,
          slotLabelFormat: {
            hour: 'numeric',
            minute: '2-digit',
            hour12: false,
          },
          firstDay: 1,
          dayHeaderFormat: {
            weekday: 'long'
          },
          eventStartEditable: true,
          eventResizableFromStart: true,
          contentHeight: "auto",
          handleWindowResize: true,
          droppable: true,
          forceEventDuration: true,
          eventOverlap: false,

          eventResize: function(eventResizeInfo) {
            var event = eventResizeInfo.event;
            if (event.start.getDay() !== event.end.getDay()) {
              eventResizeInfo.revert();
            }
          },
          eventDrop: function(eventResizeInfo) {
            var event = eventResizeInfo.event;
            if (event.start.getDay() !== event.end.getDay()) {
              eventResizeInfo.revert();
            }
          },
          eventLeave: function(eventResizeInfo) {
            const event = eventResizeInfo.event;
            event.remove();
          },
          eventContent: function(eventInfo) {
            const event = eventInfo.event;
            const id = event.id;
            if (event.title.length == 0) return "Empty Slot";
            const eventTitle = `<div>${event.title} </div>`;

            return {
              html: `<div class='d-flex flex-column'> ${eventTitle} </div> </div>`
            }
          },
          eventChange: function(info) {
            const events = calendar.getEvents();
          },

          eventReceive: function(event) {
            const events = calendar.getEvents();
            const title = event.event.title;
            const start = event.event.startStr;
            const end = event.event.endStr;
            const allDay = event.event.allDay;

            event.event.remove();

            calendar.addEvent({
              id: generate_uuidv4(),
              title: title,
              start: start,
              end: end,
              wholeDay: allDay,
            });
          },
        });

        calendar.render();

        function getEvents() {
          const events = calendar.getEvents();
        }
      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body id="body">
    <div class="row" style="width: 100%;">
      <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why have you got the fullCalendar JS file included twice in your page? The .min.js version is simply a compressed version of the .js file. They both provide the exact same functionality. You don't need them both. At best it's inefficient, at worst it could actively cause problems.

Comment: There are other oddities: Why, when you receive an external event via eventReceive, do you then remove it and replace it with another almost identical event - except for replacing "allDay" with a property called "wholeDay" which isn't recognised by fullCalendar? On the face of it, this doesn't seem to make a whole lot of sense. If you just want to explicitly set an ID you can do that without deleting and re-creating the whole event

Comment: Why do you explicitly remove the event during eventLeave? This should happen automatically anyway, as per the https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRemove docs

Comment: And `eventResizableFromStart: true` will have no effect unless you also set either `editable: true` or `eventDurationEditable: true`.

Comment: Anyway, from the description of your problem I'd guess (without having enough of your sample event data to prove it) that the problem is you've set `eventOverlap : true` and you're trying to move an all-day event to a date where there's already a timed event on that day. The two events cannot overlap, so you won't be allowed to do that.

Comment: Remember, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventOverlap says _"If a timed event occurs on the same day as an all-day event, this will qualify as an intersection. This might seem confusing in the TimeGrid views because the events don’t visually intersect because the all-day slot is separate from the timed slots. But it’s still considered an overlap."_

Comment: Thank you for your input! I cannot move allDay events from one day to another even if the calendar only hosts that one event.  It is not a problem of overlap.

Comment: Ah, I think I've found it. If you use [forceEventDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/forceEventDuration), it forces fullCalendar to set an `end` date on an event. For all-day events, the end date is always midnight on the following day (because as per the [event object documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object)) end dates in fullCalendar are **exclusive** - so if you create an all-day event for the 12th, fullCalendar will consider the `end` date to be 00:00:00 on the 13th....

Comment: ...and this causes the problem I think, because in your `eventDrop` callback you've written code which compares the day component of the start and end date, and reverts the change if the days are not equal. If you remove `forceEventDuration` from the settings, this no longer happens - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/YzBbGgp

Comment: Yes! That was it. Works perfectly! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [forceEventDuration](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/forceEventDuration), it forces fullCalendar to set an end date on an event. For all-day events, the end date is always midnight on the following day because (as per the [event object documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object)) end dates in fullCalendar are **exclusive** - so for example if you create an all-day event for the 12th, fullCalendar will consider the end date to be 00:00:00 on the 13th.

This causes the problem, because then in your `eventDrop` callback you've written code which compares the "day" component of the start and end date, and reverts the change if the days are not equal.

If you remove

```
forceEventDuration : true
```

from the settings, this no longer happens - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/YzBbGgp

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem. Excellent catch and your solution works perfectly.

Comment: Do you think that I should alter the callback in eventDrop or remove the ```forceEventDuration : true``` ?

Comment: @AriadniMak that depends on the functionality you actually want to achieve. I don't know if the eventDrop callback has value for you in other situations (e.g. when dragging timed events), or not, or whether you still need to enforce the restriction but in a different way. For example the callback could check if the event was marked allDay and then alter the way it compares the start and end date accordingly, maybe that would solve your issue.